# How to show images from array of array json

Tags: ios, swift

[This is my json](https://mywebstaging.net/ab/garnier/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=ck_4a6a758693004efa43ad311d18b30461e6a03d1f&consumer_secret=cs_41a3324c8f8e950ca75764872ae91ea4e5c9b85b)

[Here in the bottom three images part I am trying to get the respective three images in the json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkPD3.png)

But I am just able to fetch the first image in didselectrowat function. Here is my code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let detail = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController
    
    if let urlString = arrdata[indexPath.row].images.first?.src, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
            if let data = data {
                detail?.Image = UIImage(data: data)!
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    detail?.Name = arrdata[indexPath.row].name
    detail?.Name2 = arrdata[indexPath.row].name
    detail?.SH_desc = arrdata[indexPath.row].categories.first!.type
    detail?.Desc = arrdata[indexPath.row].description
    detail?.Price = arrdata[indexPath.row].price
    
    if let urlString = arrdata[indexPath.row].images.first?.src, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
            if let data = data {
                detail?.Img1 = UIImage(data: data)!
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    if let urlString = arrdata[indexPath.row].images.first?.src, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
            if let data = data {
                detail?.Img2 = UIImage(data: data)!
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    if let urlString = arrdata[indexPath.row].images.first?.src, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
            if let data = data {
                detail?.Img3 = UIImage(data: data)!
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detail!, animated: true)
}
```

Please help me out.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: ` arrdata[indexPath.row].images.first?.src` that's only the first image each time. What about  `arrdata[indexPath.row].images[1]?.src`, `arrdata[indexPath.row].images[2]?.src` etc.? Also the code is async, so `pushViewController` will be called before `details.img` are set...

Comment: arrdata[indexPath.row].images[1]?.src   -- this thing I have tried. but showing error. And I didn't get "Also the code is async, so pushViewController will be called before details.img are set" this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are always searching for the first image into the `images` array.
You should be using indexes to retrieve the correct image:

Try to change your code like this:

```
let imagesArray = arrdata[indexPath.row].images

if imagesArray.count > 0, let url = URL(string: imagesArray[0].src) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        if let data = data {
            detail?.Img1 = UIImage(data: data)!
        }
    }.resume()
}
    
if imagesArray.count > 1, let url = URL(string: imagesArray[1].src) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        if let data = data {
            detail?.Img2 = UIImage(data: data)!
        }
    }.resume()
}
    
if imagesArray.count > 2, let url = URL(string: imagesArray[2].src) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        if let data = data {
            detail?.Img3 = UIImage(data: data)!
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: That approach should work, but repeating the same code like that 3 times violates the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle. It would be better to refactor the detail struct to have an array of 3 images and write code that loops through the number of images found in the JSON and installs them into `detail`.

Comment: Luca Pizzini thank you for ur valuable response. It worked nicely